# Password change update password manager best practice

Tags: forms, passwords, keychain, forgot-password

What is the best practice for dealing with a user changing their password and letting their password managers getting the notice of the change?

If a user request a "forget password" link, the user gets often redirected to a specific page where he can set a new password. After filling this info in, the password is being set on the backend and gets redirected to the **logged-in** homepage.

But this doesn't pops up or updates the in-browser save password dialog/system/keychain/manager. They mostly get triggered when there is also a text field on the form.

I could **redirect it to the login** page, but that seems a bit stupid since the user just entered their password, and have to do it again.

I notice this with linkedin a lot and google as well, that when I changed my password, some pages still try autofilling my old password and I get a notice that my password is incorrect.

Does anyone knows how exactly cross-browser all these system work? Or isn't there a standard for triggering/updating password managers? And what seems the best practice? If you log a user auto in after a change, there is a quite big change he again forgets it in a few days. It's bizar how many people enter wrong passwords at a login screen.